# Amazon Keyspaces sync_table() doesn't see a table immediately

Tags: python, cassandra, cassandra-driver, amazon-keyspaces

I am new in `cassandra-driver==3.25.0`. I've created a model from `Model` and tried to sync it. The problem:

1. I am calling `sync_table`
2. I see that table starts creating in Keyspaces and the definition is correct
3. BUT `sync_table` raises an exception `KeyError {__table_name__}` from this line of code `table = cluster.metadata.keyspaces[ks_name].tables[raw_cf_name]`
4. I can call `sync_table` again and it is working fine after some time

So I am assuming it can some delay from Keyspaces, so do `cassandra-driver` has some sort of wait on sync table, or can you point to the documentation, please.

```
class Users(Model):
    __keyspace__ = 'aura'
    __table_name__ = 'users'
    __connection__ = 'aws_keyspace'

    user_id = columns.UUID(primary_key=True)
    tags = columns.Map(key_type=columns.Text(), value_type=columns.Text())

cluster = Cluster(...)
session = cluster.connect()
connection.register_connection('aws_keyspace', session=session, default=True)
sync_table(Users)
```

Full exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "models.py", line 69, in <module>
    sync_table(AttachmentsByUsers)
  File "python3.6/site-packages/cassandra/cqlengine/management.py", line 190, in sync_table
    _sync_table(m, connection=connection)
  File "python3.6/site-packages/cassandra/cqlengine/management.py", line 274, in _sync_table
    table = cluster.metadata.keyspaces[ks_name].tables[raw_cf_name]
KeyError: 'users'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon Keyspaces creates tables in a non-blocking way. Since its asynchronous, you may not see the table immediately. This link has guidance on how to monitor system tables to check when a table is available. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/keyspaces/latest/devguide/functional-differences.html#functional-differences.table-keyspace-management

The following query will show the status of your table in CQL

```sql
SELECT keyspace_name, table_name, status FROM system_schema_mcs.tables
WHERE keyspace_name = 'mykeyspace' AND table_name = 'mytable';
```

is the table is still being created the output of the query will look like this:

| keyspace_name | table_name | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| mykeyspace | mytable | CREATING |

If table was successfully created and is active the output of the query looks like this:

| keyspace_name | table_name | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| mykeyspace | mytable | ACTIVE |